Understanding DLL Linking in Windows
Relationship between DLL Runtime Logic and Lib Files
I am trying to understand the runtime logic of DLLs in Windows. I know that during the compilation stage, I only need to provide the lib file and the DLL import header file, but I don't quite understand how the program and compiler know the name of the DLL. I found information stating that the lib file does not record the DLL name. I attempted to change the name of the lib file, and the program was still able to find the necessary DLL. However, when I modified the DLL name, the program reported that it couldn't find "name.DLL." I don't understand how the program knows which DLL name it needs to link to. Is it recorded in the lib file?
// EXE
#include <iostream>
#include "mylib.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1\\DLLTEST\\123.lib")

int main()
{
    std::cout << Add(1, 2); 
}

// mylib.h
#pragma once
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

// MYLIB_EXPORTS should only be defined when building the DLL
#ifdef TESTDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" MYLIB_API int Add(int a, int b);

#endif // MYLIB_H


Re “I found information stating that the lib file does not record the DLL name”: Whenever you refer to outside information when asking a question on Stack Overflow, or when communicating with a colleague or writing for publication or doing any serious work, cite the source of the information. Quote specific text and give a URL, a title, an author’s name, a date and place of publication, location of the text in the document, such as chapter, clause, or page. Nobody else should have to justify why information you read somewhere on the Internet is wrong, especially when you do not cite it.

Yes, it is recorded in the lib file

Don't tag C with the C++ code.

In Windows a DLL is in fact an executable file. For that reason, the global data of the DLL will be shared among all the applications using it. Windows has a number of system function that allow to get the addresses of the exported functions.
At run time, the importation lib file acts as a relay: it is responsable for finding the addresses of the exported functions, and then all the calls that are done to the statically linked lib file functions are relayed to the DLL ones.
That explains why the name of the lib file is not important, while the name of the DLL file is: the lib has to be able to locate its companion DLL.
